# How to Interprete Constant Intercept in Log Models?

Tags: interpretation, logarithm, intercept

Even though this seems like an especially simple question, I am not 100% sure about what the constant in a log-log model, log-level, or level-log model means. For example, in

log(weight) = 8.29 - 0.0039(smoking) - .00037149(drinking).

I understand what the variables do to log(weight), but what does the intercept, 8.29, do? Does it = weight when the independent var.s are 0, or does it = log(weight), necessitating another step to figure out what (weight) by itself is?

Comment: Do you mean an intercept parameter that is estimated, or do you mean a term in the model that has a constant effect (an offset)? The former controls (estimated from the data) when the predicted log(weight) is zero and is much the same thing as an intercept in a linear model. The latter usually leads to a weight/exp(offset) interpretation for the model (e.g. events per time unit).

Comment: @Achim I mean an intercept that is estimated.  Still not sure what you mean by it being the same thing as in a linear model. Could you explain a but further? This is something that I have heard conflicting opinions about, even though I know what the math should ostensibly mean.

Answer (score 0):

I write your estimated regression model as
$$ \text{weight} = C - \beta_1\cdot\text{smoking} - \beta_2\cdot\text{drinking}$$
Just exponentiate:
\begin{align}
   \text{weight} &= e^{C - \beta_1\cdot\text{smoking} - \beta_2\cdot\text{drinking} } \\
  &= e^C e^{-\beta_1\cdot\text{smoking}} e^{- \beta_2\cdot\text{drinking}}  \\
&=  e^C \left(e^{-\text{smoking}}  \right)^\beta_1   \left(e^{-\text{drinking}}  \right)^\beta_2 
\end{align}
so the (additive) intercept in the logged model, corresponds to a (multiplicative) constant in the original multiplicative model.